# Downloading multiple files using Selenium click()?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Using Firefox/Python/Selenium-- I am able to use `click()` on a file link on a webpage to download it, and the file downloads to my Downloads folder as expected.

However, when I add more lines to `click()` on more than 1 link, the script no longer runs as expected. Instead of the files being downloaded, they are all opening in separate browser windows, which all close after the script completes.

Is this by design or is there a way around it or a better way to download multiple files on a webpage?

This is the website in question: https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Pages/igdeskbook.aspx

I am trying to download the links to the Introduction and all parts of Volumes 1-4.

I have a dictionary of the locators:

```
IgDeskbookPageMap = dict(IgDeskbookBannerXpath = "//div[contains(text(), 'The Inspector General Deskbook')]",
                         IgDeskbookIntroId     = "anch_202",
                         IgDeskbookVol1Part1Id = "anch_203",
                         IgDeskbookVol1Part2Id = "anch_204",
                         IgDeskbookVol1Part3Id = "anch_205",
                         IgDeskbookVol1Part4Id = "anch_206",
                         IgDeskbookVol2Id      = "anch_207",
                         IgDeskbookVol3Id      = "anch_208",
                         IgDeskbookVol4Part1Id = "anch_209",
                         IgDeskbookVol4Part2Id = "anch_210",
                         IgDeskbookVol4Part3Id = "anch_211"
```

This is the method:

```
 def click(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
    self.wait_until_element_clickable(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).click()
```

These are the click() calls (there are more than 3, but just truncating here for space:

```
self.click(10,
                 "id",
                 IgDeskbookPageMap['IgDeskbookIntroId']
      )
      self.click(10,
                 "id",
                 IgDeskbookPageMap['IgDeskbookVol1Part1Id']
      )
      self.click(10,
                 "id",
                 IgDeskbookPageMap['IgDeskbookVol1Part2Id']
      )
```

Comment: could you share the details to which website and what links you are trying to click to make the download? Also what code is getting used by you for this.

Comment: Can you provide more information as the the type of links: files, pdfs, other pages?  This would help to understand why new tabs (which is a setting) opens instead of downloading a file.

Comment: @nullpointer I've edited the question, does that help?

Comment: @BobSmall Question edited-- the files are PDFs

Comment: @Vince - clicking on the files redirect to a newer tab, in which case the behaviour seems justified.

Comment: @nullpointer That may be because of the default behavior that Firefox uses for PDFs? I was able to go into Settings > Preferences > Applications > change PDF to "Save File" instead of default "Preview in Firefox". Manually clicking on the links afterwards shows that they download into the folder as expected. Strange why click() on one would be OK, but click() on multiple ones make it default back to the Preview setting. Is this a limitation with the browser that I will just have to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following code for launching Firefox and now the download behavior works as expected when clicking on each file:

```
     profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
     profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
     profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
     profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
     profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf,application/x-pdf')
     profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf")
     profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
     self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to download such multiple files if ***opened in different tabs*** could be to follow these algorithmic steps in your own coding language :

```
for( all such links) :
   click() the pdf link
   findElement the download element
   click() the download link
   close the tab
   switch back to last tab  //should ideally be completed with previous step
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to piece together some code and get my original task working.