# navigate to the next page in a for loop without failing the loop?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to download all the `pdf` files from the webpage at https://iaeme.com/ijmet/index.asp.

The page has different links, inside each link there are multiple downloads and more pages. I am trying to navigate the next page and continue the loop.

```
package flow;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileList.FileName;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import jxl.common.Assert;
//kindly ignore the imports 


public class excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User_2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();
        d.manage().window().maximize();
        d.get("https://iaeme.com/ijmet/index.asp");                  
        java.util.List<WebElement> catvalues=d.findElements(By.className("issue"));
        for(int i=0;i<=catvalues.size();i++){  
            catvalues.get(i).click();                    
            java.util.List<WebElement> downcount=d.findElements(By.linkText("Download"));
            System.out.println(downcount.size());

            for(int k=1;k<=downcount.size();k++){  
                downcount.get(k).click();                                                
                Thread.sleep(5000);                          
            }

            d.navigate().back();
            catvalues = d.findElements(By.className("issue"));
        }
    }  
}
```

I tried different methods which failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the https://iaeme.com/ijmet/index.asp page, you can note that for each class with id **lik** there is the **onclick** attribute. In this attribute there are the infos that you need in order to open all the interested pages.

Example:

The pattern is

```
onclick="journalpissue('8','9','IJMET')"
```

and from this you have to create this link

> https://iaeme.com/ijmet/issues.asp?JType=IJMET&VType=8&IType=9

So, in this example:

> VType=8 IType=9 JType=IJMET

Once you have all the links, you can iterate on all the pages.

For each page you have to get the value of the "href" attribute of all the elements with class id **jounl**.

Once you have the pdf links, I continued using the "curl" command. If you want to download all the files with selenium, could be useful this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664671/3881320

```
public class Stackoverflow {

public static void main(String args[]) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://iaeme.com/ijmet/index.asp");
        java.util.List<WebElement> likValues = driver.findElements(By.className("lik"));
        LinkedList<String> allUrl = new LinkedList<>();
        String baseUrl = "https://iaeme.com/ijmet/";
        for (WebElement el : likValues) {
            String journalpissue = el.getAttribute("onclick");
            String relativeUrl = parseJournalpissue(journalpissue);
            allUrl.add(relativeUrl);
        }

        for (String url : allUrl) {
            analyzePage(driver, baseUrl + url, true);
        }

    }

private static void analyzePage(WebDriver driver, String url, boolean searchOtherPages) {
        driver.get(url);
        List<WebElement> allA = null;
        if (searchOtherPages) {
            List<WebElement> tdlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='contant'] tr td"));
            WebElement pages = tdlist.get(tdlist.size() - 1);
            System.out.println(pages.getText());
            allA = pages.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        }

        java.util.List<WebElement> jounl = driver.findElements(By.className("jounl"));
        for (WebElement wel : jounl) {
            String href = wel.getAttribute("href");
            if (href.contains(".pdf")) {
                System.out.println("File to download: " + href);
                downloadFile(href);
            }
        }

        if (allA != null) {
            for (WebElement a : allA) {
                String href = a.getAttribute("href");
                System.out.println(href);
                analyzePage(driver, href, false);
            }
        }
    }


private static void downloadFile(String file) {
        try {
            String[] CMD_COMPOSED = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "curl -O " + file,};
            String output;

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD_COMPOSED);
            StringBuilder outputBuilder;
            outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                outputBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            output = outputBuilder.toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Stackoverflow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static String parseJournalpissue(String journalpissue) {
        String finalUrl = null;

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(journalpissue, "'");
        st.nextToken();
        String vType = st.nextToken();
        st.nextToken();
        String iType = st.nextToken();
        st.nextToken();
        String jType = st.nextToken();

        finalUrl = "issues.asp?JType=" + jType + "&VType=" + vType + "&IType=" + iType;
        System.out.println(finalUrl);
        return finalUrl;

    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I didn't consider that in one of these pages (where there are the pdf files to download) there could be more pages (your "more pages", in your description). In order to do this, you could use the same approach.

**EDIT:**

The infos about the number of pages are in:

[image]

That is in the table with classname "contant". In particular, is the last element.

So:

```
List<WebElement> tdlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='contant'] tr td"));
WebElement pages = tdlist.get(tdlist.size() - 1);
```

We are interested about the "a" tagName:

```
List<WebElement> allA = pages.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Now we also have the url of all the other pages. We can use the same approach of before in order to donwload the pdf files.

Comment: Thank you buddy , i will try this  .

Comment: buddy i could download but , i could not navigate to the next page , can u help me ??

Comment: I edited the answer and inserted the part that allow you to navigate on the other pages. I'm sure there are other (best) ways to obtain the final goal. I hope I helped you to understand how to think about find a solution in this kind of problems.

Comment: Now i get it buddy , thank you very much - this means a lot !!

Comment: @SarathChandar Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers